# How to work on your own Wordpress theme when you can't open the zip file in your IDE?

Tags: wordpress

I created a project in the theme folder of wordpress. I followed a few tutorials and saw that they were able to check the changes they made directly on Wordpress. 
However, after I downloaded my starter project on wordpress, i was unable to open the zip file in Visual Code (i also tried sublime and atom) to start building my website.
Do I need to unzip the file and re zip it each time?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Extension for Visual Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-deploy-reloaded

This can also deploy to a zip file. I myself use a local apache server for WP Development and use the extension to deploy to it.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded it but it's still not working!

Comment: Please give some more infos on what you did so far.

Comment: I'm sorry...i didn't realize some responded. I fixed the issue. thank you!